# Documentation option in GitHub

Tags: github, documentation, markdown, wiki, github-pages

I'm writing documentation for a GitHub project and wondering where should I write it to. There seems to be three options: [GitHub Pages](http://pages.github.com/), GitHub Wiki or a set of Markdown files in the repository (e.g. under docs/ directory) similar to the README.md. Understandably I don't want to write the same documentation to multiple places so I have to pick one.

So what are the differences, pros and cons between the options? Any experience or thoughts about using them especially for project documentation? Also is there other options in addition to the three?

Answer (score 2):

that is a very good question which I personally decide on a change-frequency and number-of-contributors basis.

As an example: in one of our projects (a c++ library) we create a HTML documentation with *doxygen* once in a while (e.g. while updating the master release branch). That's a perfect match for quasi-static **gh-pages**. In addition you get a sub domain for it `http://<user>.github.io/<project>/` and you can register your own domains on top of it.

An other project contains developer and user documentation (a C++ program). I personally prefer to *provide a main workflow for developers* in **.md files** to keep them consistent with the mainline development. Changes will be reviewed by pull requests first.

But for *user documentation* we choose the build-in **wiki** since it is very easy to edit and modify - one can even allow modifications by non-members of a team.